# Resolving workspace dependencies for Virgo in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, springsource-dm-server, eclipse-virgo

I'm looking to get started with Eclipse Virgo, so I grabbed the required plugins for Eclipse based on the Programmer Guide.

Next, I started two new projects in my Eclipse workspace, both configured as Virgo bundles (call these A and B). Then, I created a new class `com.foo.Bar` in bundle B. I modified the Manifest of bundle B to export `com.foo`, saved. Last, I imported `com.foo` in bundle A.

Bundle A's manifest has an error:

> Import-Package: com.foo [0.0.0, oo) could not be resolved

What do I need to do to configure Eclipse to resolve dependencies using the projects in my workspace?

I've already tried adding bundle B to the build path of bundle A, but this makes no difference. (It's worth noting that adding bundle B to the build path of bundle A, even if it had worked, isn't a suitable solution because the dependency management needs to be done differently.)

Details of note:

- Virgo: 2.1
- Eclipse: 3.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that:

1. MANIFEST.MF *must* be located in src/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
2. "EclipseRT OSGi Bundle" is one of the project facets
3. A Virgo Web Server Runtime must also be specified 
   (use the Runtimes tab in the Project Facets window)

Steps to resolve dependencies:

1. Open properties on bundle B (right click -> Properties)
2. Choose "Project References"
3. Check the checkbox next to bundle A

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by using STS (Spring Tool Suite) and the tooling for Spring dm Server and associating each bundle with virgo runtime.

Comment: were you able to avoid setting project references and having the dependencies resolve in STS?